# Specifying Elements for jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<ul>` containing `<h2>` headings with text below each. I want to be able to display or hide the text below by clicking the each of the headings.

How can I tell jquery to only display the text from within the same `<li>` when the heading is clicked without creating a seperate if statement for each `<li>`?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>heading</h2>
        <div id='step'>
            text text text
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>heading</h2>
        <div id='step'>
            text text text
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
    $("li").click(function () {
        if ($("#step").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#step").slideDown("slow");
        } else {
            $("#step").slideUp("slow");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Start by correcting your markup. id attribute has to be unique..so you can't have more than one step id in the document. change it to class if you need to target those elements.

Answer (score 2):

For a start you have duplicate ids, this is incorrect. Replace them with classes or other identifiers as ids should be unique.

Secondly use `$(this)` to reference the element that was clicked.

HTML

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <h2>heading</h2>
  <div class='step'>
   text text text
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <h2>heading</h2>
  <div class='step'>
   text text text
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
$("li").click(function () {
    $(this).children('.step').slideToggle('slow');
});​
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JGZRN/

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that you are trying to target a div with id step but there are multiple divs with that id. Use different id's for the div

It can be fixe as follows:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <h2>heading</h2>
  <div>
   text text text
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <h2>heading</h2>
  <div>
   text text text
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>​
```

and the js

```
$("li").click(function () {
    if ($(this).children('div').is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).children('div').slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        $(this).children('div').slideUp("slow");
    }
});​
```

Do note that in this example it assumes you are using only one div in the li

Comment: +1, this is a correct answer, maybe not what the user was expecting, but negative vote on this seems excessive to me

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :) $(this) refers to the list element that has been clicked, then it "finds" the p tag under it and "slideToggle"'s which either slides up or down depending on its current state.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('li').click(function(){
            $(this).find('p').slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>heading 1</h2>
        <p>Text text text</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>heading 2</h2>
        <p>Text text text</p>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `id="step"` by `class="step"` in the divs, you can use this code:

```
$("li").click(function () {
     var div = $(this).find(".step");
     if (div.is(":hidden")) {
       div.slideDown("slow");
     } 
     else {
       div.slideUp("slow");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

html:

```
<ul>
  <li>
   <h2>heading</h2>
     <div id='step'>
       text text text
     </div>
   </li>
   <li>
     <h2>heading</h2>
       <div id='step'>
         text text text
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul>​
```

js:

```
$('ul li h2').click(function() {
  $('#step').toggle('slow', function() {
   // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

here a preview fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wandarkaf/2Pnz7/

Hope this helps.​